# Hiding gridview rows takes two tries

Tags: c#, gridview, hide

I created a gridview with textboxes in the footer for the insert function.  I have the footer defaulted to hidden.  I also added an 'Add' button to the first column of the header that I will use to show the footer. I also want this button to hide the gridview rows and the button itself, effectively keeping them from hitting the add button when they're already in insert mode, and bringing the footer to the top of the gridview.

(VS2008 C#)

```
protected void btnNewUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       GridView2.Rows[i].Visible = false;

   }
   GridView2.ShowFooter = true;
   GridView2.HeaderRow.FindControl("btnNewUser").Visible = false;
}
```

When I click the button the first time, the footer displays, but the rows and button stay visible.  When I click the button a second time, the rows and button become hidden.  How do I get this all to work in one click?

Edit: If I comment out GridView2.ShowFooter = true; it will hide the rows just fine.  Is there some kind of a postback/refresh/databind, etc.happening when I show the footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, changing the value of the `ShowFooter` property marks the gridview for rebinding.
The implementation looks as follows:

```
set
{
    bool showFooter = this.ShowFooter;
    if (value != showFooter)
    {
        this.ViewState["ShowFooter"] = value;
        if (base.Initialized)
        {
            base.RequiresDataBinding = true;
        }
    }
}
```

A possible workaround could be to set to footer visibility instead. (And always have `ShowFooter` set to true)

```
GridView2.FooterRow.Visible = true/false;
```